# Develop a plugin editor for eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a question for you. My teacher proposed a couple of thesis to me. Basically to develop a plugin for eclipse. There are 2 options:

1)An editor for A-SPL language with syntax highlighting, auto completation of the cose, errors detection and so on........to help people that need to use S-APL

2)An editor to help people to design GUI in S-APL......something like a framework where you can drag widgets and there is a kind of automatic completation of the code....

The thesis should last 4 months......i should not implement everything but make a kind of prototype that maybe in the future someone will finish and make properly work.

I never did something like this so i would like to know if it is difficult, which skills are needed, which languages i should know to create eclipse plugins (for example i know java and python) and so on......to figure out if it is something i can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to look into the [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) (for a textual editor) and [Graphiti](http://www.eclipse.org/graphiti/) (for a graphical editor) projects.

Comment: +1 for XText. I didn't know graphiti. Do you think it's suitable for building a model editor based on custom Ecore metamodel ?

Comment: @Gab I haven't used Graphiti myself, but I think that's exactly what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need Java for Eclipse plugins.
You need to read a book / the eclipse plugin wiki about Eclipse architecture as it's critical to know the paradigms in use.

There's an example XML plugin editor that you can create from the 'New Plugin' wizard which would be a good starting point for the first option.

good luck. :)